# Kafka JDBC Connect: Insert key based on multiple values in message fields

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have the following json on a topic that the JDBC connector publishes to

```
{"APP_SETTING_ID":9,"USER_ID":10,"APP_SETTING_NAME":"my_name","SETTING_KEY":"my_setting_key"}
```

Here's my connector file

```
name=data.app_setting
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
poll.interval.ms=500
tasks.max=4
mode=timestamp
query=SELECT APP_SETTING_ID, APP_SETTING_NAME, SETTING_KEY,FROM MY_TABLE with (nolock)
timestamp.column.name=LAST_MOD_DATE
topic.prefix=data.app_setting

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

I now want to insert a key to this message by multiplying the two integer fields - `APP_SETTING_ID` and `USER_ID`. So the key for this message becomes `9*10 = 90`

Is this transformation possible through Connect and if so could someone please shed light on it

Comment: There is no built-in way to multiply a value in Kafka Connect. However, that doesn't mean you couldn't write your own transformer to do it. Otherwise, it would require your producer code or some other Kafka Streams/KSQL job to do that logic. Or you can write the multiplication in the SQL query

Comment: Can you point me to relevant documentation for writing your own transformers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try seeing how far you can get with

```
query=SELECT APP_SETTING_ID, APP_SETTING_NAME, SETTING_KEY, (APP_SETTING_ID*USER_ID) as _key FROM MY_TABLE with (nolock)
```

Then add an ExtractKey transform

```
transforms=AddKeys,ExtractKey
# this make a map
transforms.AddKeys.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.AddKeys.fields=_key  
# this gets one field from the map 
transforms.ExtractKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractKey.field=_key
```

Comment: Hmm didnt think of adding it in the SQL. That would do for me. Thanks